# is there a more efficient way to filter regex match string?

Tags: regex

```
var s = '/home/src/_layouts/default.pug';// I wanna '_layouts/default'
var regex = /(src\/.*)/;
var m = s.match(regex);
var t = m[0].match(/([^(src\/)].*)(?=\..*$)/)[0];
console.log(t);// outputs "_layouts/default"
```

it works but no elegant enough, I wanna do it more efficient, anyone can help me? thanks.

Comment: You should elaborate on the desired behavior more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you're after is `/src\/([^.]*)\..+/`.

It'll match the `src`, then capture everything before the dot. `[^.]` is a negated character class ("match everything except these characters"), meaning it'll only get the filename and not the extension.

Answer (score 0):

What about this regex:

```
src\/(.*)\.\w+
```

Try it on Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/bW2qS6/1

Your JS code would then be:

```
var s = '/home/src/_layouts/default.pug';
var t = s.match(/src\/(.*)\.\w+/)[1];
console.log(t);
```